# objectClass in openldap.

Tags: openldap

I am working on openldap in my linux box (centos) as testing.I create a base file to discuss with you about objectClass functionality & its impact if we not write.I write objectClass two times i.e top and domain .What does it mean ? The 2nd one is drived from the firect objectClass like parents child relation ?

```
[root@srv1 openldap]# vim base.ldif 
base.ldif 
dn: dc=test,dc=local 
dc: test 
objectClass: top 
objectClass: domain
```

Now I create add two OUs and does not add objectClass:top in both sales and marketing.

To add two OUs i.e Sales and Marketing

```
dn: ou=Sales,dc=test,dc=local 
ou: Sales 
objectClass:organizationalUnit 

dn: ou=Marketing,dc=test,dc=local 
ou: Marketing 
objectClass: organizationalUnit
```

The confusion is should use all the parent objectClass and chield objectClass ? If we not add what impact will be  on the structure ? In the following I use objectClass top and organizationalunit

```
dn: ou=Sales,dc=test,dc=local 
ou: Sales 
objectClass: top 
objectClass:organizationalUnit 


dn: ou=Marketing,dc=test,dc=local 
ou: Marketing 
objectClass: top 
objectClass: organizationalUnit
```

Please guide me which one is correct ?

thanks 
garden

Comment: Please go back to your old questions and accept answers where applicable. People are unlikely to help you if you don't even acknowledge their time with ticking this accept mark on the question.

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the entire objectClass chain all the way to 'top', unless you can be confident that your LDAP server will automatically insert missing base classes for you.